# What common plastic types would be most compatible with pool water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, plastics, environmental-chemistry

What thin-film plastic types are most compatible with typical pool water (pH 7.2, normally 5ppm chlorine but up to 15ppm on occasion) in full sun?

I'm finding that most standard film materials degrade quickly.  How does polyethylene faire?  Mylar?  Teflon?  Polyetherimide?  A table of such material compatibility would be wonderful.

Comment: It's more of an issue with in being film and with sunlight.

Comment: Note that pool ropes and buoys are often polyethylene or polypropylene because they're more resistant than nylon (and float), but they have UV inhibitors to extend life.